# Simple Equation Does my proof work?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

Its the inequality equation $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b
| $

I managed this by cases.

Let $c = a$ and $d=b$ if $a>b $

let $c = b$ and $d = a$ if $b>a $

if $a=b$ let $a=c$

Hence we have $|c+d| \leq |c|+|d| $ where $c>d$

Case 1
if  $d > 0$   then $|c+d| = |c|+|d|$ $\forall c $

Case 2 
if $c < 0$ then $|c+d| = |c|+|d|$ $\forall d $

Case 3 if $ c \vee d =0$ then $|c+d| = |c|+|d|$

Case 4   $c > 0$  and $d < 0$ then $|c+d| < |c|+|d|$ $ \forall$ $c$ and $d$

But i want to solve this directly not by cases.

I think that it can be done by treating a and b as vectors described by two components up down ($y$) and left right ($x$) where $|a|$ is the length of the vector $\vec a$ described as:

$$|\vec a|=  \sqrt {x^2_a + y^2_a}$$
$$|\vec b|=  \sqrt {x^2_b + y^2_b}$$

And $|\vec a+\vec b|$ would be the length of $\vec a$ plus $\vec b$ or $|\vec a+\vec b|= \sqrt {(x_a +x_b)^2 + (y_a +y_b )^2 }$

thus $|\vec a+\vec b| \leq |\vec a|+|\vec b| $ = $ \sqrt {(x_a +x_b)^2 + (y_a +y_b )^2 } \leq \sqrt {x^2_a + y^2_a} + \sqrt {x^2_b + y^2_b}$ now since we cant have negative length we can square both sides.

$ (x_a +x_b)^2 + (y_a +y_b )^2  \leq  x^2_a + y^2_a + x^2_b + y^2_b + 2(x^2_b + y^2_b)^{1/2} (x^2_a + y^2_a)^{1/2}$

$ ( x_a x_b + y_a y_b) \leq (x^2_b + y^2_b)^{1/2} (x^2_a + y^2_a)^{1/2}$

rhs = $(x^2_a x^2_b  + y^2_a x^2_b + x^2_a y^2_b  + y^2_a y^2_b)$ ?

anyway from here it feels like im screwed on the plus side the right hand side is always $0 \geq  $ and the left side can be positive or negative. oddly whenever the x and y components of the vectors have a magnitude greater then or equal to 1 this seems to stand up fairly obviously its just when it has pieces under magnitude 1 that things get really ugly though only intuitively it feels obvious that when none of the components or either vector are $0$ the right side should be bigger then the left.

any ideas on a different way to approach this? thanks.

EDIT: i Originally did exactly what Rolighed has written down and came to the conclusion that $|x| |y| \geq |xy|$ as he did at the end of his proof but i tossed out the idea on the thought that i couldn't square both sides on the thought that $4 \geq -5$ but $4^2 < -5^2$

EDIT2: it turns out that this inequality can be squared because both sides are positive no matter what which makes if $ x \geq y$ and $ y \geq 0$  then $x^2 \geq y^2$  since we know both sides of our inequality must be 0 or bigger we can square them and do the easy proof as shown by Rolighed. My confusion of your explanation Rolighed how you come you could square both sides took me too long to realize why =(

Comment: There are two more common and elegant ways to handle the $c$ and $d$ assignment you have at the top. One option is to write $c=\max(a,b), d=\min(a,b)$. This will give you exactly the same results as the one you have. The other option is to say "Assume without loss of generality that $a\geq b$." The phrase "without loss of generality" is used for exactly this kind of thing when you don't want to introduce extra variables, and you don't want to do the _exact_ same proof one more time for the case $b\geq a$.

Comment: One of them is clearly larger than (or equal to) the other, so you might as well decide that that's the one that is called $a$. "Without loss of generality" is sometimes abbreviated to wlog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well.. I learned this proof for the inequality.

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^k$. Observe that

$|x+y|^2=(x+y)(x+y)=|x|^2+|y|^2+2xy\le |x|^2+|y|^2+2|xy| \le|x|^2+|y|^2+2|x||y|=(|x|+|y|)^2$

In the last inequality, we have used the Cauchy/Schwarz Inequality ($|xy|\le|x||y|$). For $k>1$ multiplication is exchanged by vector product.

Comment: thats what i tried to do originally but can you really square both side like that? i talked myself out of this exact proof by thinking $0.1 \geq -2$ and then squaring both sides it doesn't hold up why can we do it here?

Comment: Well.. I'm not completely sure what you're asking. The function $x^{2}$ is increasing when $x\ge 0$. This means exactly that for $x_2\ge x_1\ge 0$ we have that $x_2^2 \ge x_1^2$. But since this is only true for $x\ge 0$, you're example with $0.1\ge -2$ is of course not included. If you're not sure how we're getting from $|x+y|^2\le (|x|^2+|y|^2)^2$ to $|x+y|\le (|x|^2+|y|^2)$, we're just using the map $\sqrt{x}$ which is also increasing for $x\ge 0$. Btw I'm happy to help :D

Comment: Rolighed whats (1/2)^2 and is it bigger than 1/2. i think oyu mean when $ x_1 \geq 1$ then $x_2^2 \geq x_1^2$

Comment: Ups.. I made a mistake in the comment above.. it is suppose to be "...we're getting from $|x+y|^2\le(|x|+|y|)^2$ to $|x+y|\le(|x|+|y|)$..."

Comment: Well.. thats of course $\frac{1}{4}$ and is less than $\frac{1}{2}$ :)

Comment: my point is if you start running your $x_1$ into the equation you wrote down where $ 0 < x_1 < 1 $ you go straight to 0 not to infinity so clearly the function isnt increasing in that range cause it got smaller.

Comment: Hi Faust7. I'm getting a little confused and I have to say that I don't quite follow you. Which equation are you referring to? Also remember that increasing just means that for $x_1>x_2$ you have that $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$. Both $x^2$ and $\sqrt{x}$ has this property for $x\ge0$

Comment: omg i get it we can Square the equation because we both side are positive because of the absolute value sign

Comment: Yep :) Good question and nice to be asked about specific. Must admit that I got some nerves when you appeared to be disagreing :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to simplify your argument. I think it's inevitable to have to resort to some sort of case analysis.

**Case 1: $b=0$**. Obvious. (Right?)

**Case 2: $b\neq0$**. It's enough to prove that $|1+a/b|\leq1+|a/b|$, since if this inequality is true we can multiply by $|b|$ to get the inequality we want. Let $x=a/b$, just to save the trouble of writing $a/b$. So we want to prove that $|1+x|\leq1+|x|$.

**Case 2(a): $x\geq0$**. Easy -- $|x|=x$ and we get $1 + x\leq 1 + x$, which is true.

**Case 2(b): $x\leq0$**. In this case $|x|=-x$. We get $1 + x\leq 1 - x$, which, if we solve for $x$, is the same as saying that $2x \leq 0$, i.e., $x\leq0$.

Do you have an intuition for why this inequality should be true, and what it means?

Comment: If you want intuition on the situation id look at it like a vector where if vectors a and b are in the same quadrant as each other then its an equality but if they are not its an in equality. that being said you can but the same logic to you $a/b$ equation when a and b have the same sign its an equality when there signs differ you have an inequality same idea but harder to visualize in my head. also your case 2 is flawless it answers everything but x=0 why'd you break it up? not sure why but its easier to picture something in 2D for me